# How to check type parameter?

Tags: c#

I have class

```
class ManagerCar : IBlalba
{
   public void Render(IViewTemplate template)
   {
   }
}
```

and I know what the parameter template is `CarViewTemplate` I want check type and throw exception if `IViewTemplate != CarViewTemplate`

I can do check `if(template is typeof(CarViewTemplate))`.

But I have many `Managers`.

I want check this type on compilation and with help attribute like `[IsType(typeof(CarViewTemplate))]`

Is it possible ?

**UPDATE**
I have interface with `Render(IViewTemplate template)`

Comment: If you can’t use an `IViewTemplate`, don’t accept one. The compile-time check you’re looking for is `CarViewTemplate template`.

Comment: I am probably missing something important here, but why don't you just make the tempate parameter the CarViewTemplate type?

Comment: As soon as you start doing lots of `typeof` checks, you know that you have a code smell.

Comment: If you have an interface with `Render(IViewTemplate template)`, then why isn't `ManagerCar : SuchAnInterface`?

Comment: @Dimitar Dimitrov, Your sound like good

Comment: Write override method exactly with CarViewTemplate param.

Answer (score 2):

This type of check already exists in the compiler, no need to try to help it.

Simply change your method signature to this:

```
public void RenderCar(CarViewTemplate template)
```

Comment: I'm actually assuming this answer is unusable, but the main problem here is that this information (that it is unusable) is not in any way or form spelled out in the question. I'm assuming there is a reason the OP cannot just change the code, but since this isn't spelled out, I want to provoke that information to appear.