# How to check typeof parameters in method?

Tags: c#, code-contracts

How to check typeof parameters in method with help code contracts?

I need check type argument in method

Comment: Do you mean the type of objects passed into your method or the types that are specified for generic parameters?

Comment: Are you sure generics is not the way to go?

Comment: If you have requirements to the type of the arguments to a method, why aren't you simply writing the right type for the parameters to it to begin with?

Comment: As a mediator I would expect a better question. What have you tried? Have you tried `if (arg1.GetType() == typeof(SomeClass))`?

Comment: Are you asking the same question that you asked 30 min ago, just with less information this time? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975546/how-to-check-type-parameter

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
public void MyMethod(object parameter)
{
    if (parameter.GetType() == typeof(Int32))
    {
        //Do some stuff
    }
}
```

In continuation to your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975546/how-to-check-type-parameter)

```
class ManagerCar : IBlalba
{
    public void Render(IViewTemplate template)
    {
        if (template.GetType() == typeof(CarViewTemplate))
        {
            //Do some stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't use contracts as requested by OP.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it:

```
Contract.Requires(yourParameter is YourType);
```

Although I have to say this sounds like a pretty bad idea, unless you're required to use underspecified types for interface implementation reasons.